# How to get the particular data using id from json file using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i need one help.I need to fetch data from my data.json file using the unique id.I am explaining my code below.

```
 $scope.editProfileData=function(){
         var editid={'id':2};
         $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'profile.json',
         data:editid
     }).then(function successCallback(response){

     },function errorCallback(response) {

     });

     }
```

Here i need when the condition (`id==2`) will match in json file it will fetch those specific data.Please help me.

Comment: are you fetching data from a json file?

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
//...
}).then(function successCallback(response){
    var i, l = response.data.length;
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
        if( response.data[i].id == 2){
            fetch( response.data[i]); // your fetch code here
            break;
        }
    }
}).
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the Ajax call and then evaluate the response. For example:

```
[...]
   .then(function successCallback(response){
        if (response.id == "2") {
            doSomeStuff();
        }
[...]
```